# uint8_t * const LCDMem = (uint8_t *) &LCDM3; meaning

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

```
uint8_t * const LCDMem = (uint8_t *) &LCDM3;
```

This code is used in msp430fg4618 trainer kit for lcd configuration.
Could any one please explain the meaning of the above mentioned code?

It allows use of `array LCDMem[]`? I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `(type) value` is called a *cast* and implements conversion from one type to another.

The code in your example casts one pointer, the address of `LCDM3`, to a pointer of a different type. This enables access to the contents of `LCDM3` through the `LCDMem` pointer as if it were a contiguous array of bytes (8-bit unsigned integers).

For example, `LDCM3` could be a structure object, or the first element of an array of structures. The above cast would allow one to read and write the individual bytes of the underlying object(s).

Comment: thank you.i am a beginner to the embedded c programming, could you elaborate a little more on this aspect, also can you guide me where to, start studying for embedded c.

Comment: @pristal It's hard to do so without more context, since I'm not familiar with the specifics of msp430fg4618. What I can recommend is picking up a good book on C, such as the classic "The C Programming Language", which is a surprisingly pleasant and beginner-friendly read.

Answer (score 3):

LCDMem is not arrray, it is a pointer. This code assigns to LCDMem new address - LCDM3's, so after execution LCDMem will point to LCDM3. Can't say how many bytes allocated for LCDM3, may be array, may be just one.